# Fire OS on RPI?

Tags: pi-2, android

Has anyone tried to create any sort of file that allows Fire OS(Amazon's Fire operating system) to run on the rpi? I can't seem to find any sites on google that provide the necessary files.

Comment: Fire Stick gen1 is esentially a Raspberry Pi running Fire OS

Comment: The source code is available : https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200203720

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not going to happen. Amazon's FireOS is based on Android, but is a closed, proprietary system.

Since there isn't even a usable version of Android, FireOS is extremely unlikely to ever become available.